# iOS button morph to loading

Tags: buttons, ios, progress-bar, loading

In Android, the native button in material style has a "loading" state. This loading state can also be "disabled" state. It looks like this:

HD Screencast - https://gfycat.com/IncompatibleConfusedBergerpicard

[image: GIF]

The buttons in iOS look like this, on the right:

[image]

Does anyone have any design guidelines on how the "loading" state would be?

Comment: If I'm not forgetting, I haven't seen loading anim inside button in iOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As per the iOS Guidelines you can give a shot at this!**

[image: Loading Spinner]

[image: Before Click]    [image: After Click]

**Updated Image:**

Note: This is for Download Functionality. For a Progress there's a loader displayed after a button is clicked.

[image: As per iOS Guidelines for Native Button Loading.]

**This One:**

[image: iOS loader]

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/controls/progress-indicators/

Comment: Very interesting thank you @mehul - however these buttons look very custom. These do not look like the standard buttons of the iOS platform. I was looking for a "loading state of a button" which is true to the iOS style guidelines and iOS look and feel. Is there any native buttons in apps by Apple you see that has a button with loading state?

Comment: There does not exist such a native design which you are looking for in the iOS Human Interface Guidelines. However, I have Updated the answer for the available Guidelines Loading on a Button Click. Hope that helped you!

Comment: Thanks very much! This is a real big help! I noticed that in iOS changing text and border color seem to morph.

Comment: Exactly!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Loding state button]

Three options for Loading Button State

Comment: Thank you @NAP but these are not in iOS style.

Answer (score 0):

[The iOS loader looks like this:](https://www.cssscript.com/demo/ios-style-loading-spinner-with-pure-css-ispinner/)

[image]

Comment: Thank you @RobE, this I know, but I was wanting to see how iOS style incorporates a "loading state" into buttons. True to the iOS style guidelines.

Comment: I can't find anything in the iOS guidelines about this kind of element. I think you'll have to go custom.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I know they have a circular loading icon button in App store. It is a cloud download icon, and when press it turns to square with ring around it, and the ring gets thicker. Do you recall seeing any loading icons in iOS apps?